# Ruby: how to iterate over an array of hash items?

Tags: ruby

```
irb> pp config
[{"file"=>"/var/tmp"},
 {"size"=>"1024"},
 {"modified"=>"03/28/2012"}]
=> nil
```

In the code,

```
config.each do |d|
  # then how to break d into (k, v)???
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

```
config.each do |hash|
  (k,v),_ = *hash
end
```

Comment: @Cupcake `*{ "size"=>"1024" }` will give you `[["size","1024"]]`. Now in `(k,v),_ = [["size","1024"]]`. as per parallel assignment, `(k,v) = ["size","1024"]`. Now `k,v = ["size","1024"]`.. again parallel assignment, thus `k = "size"` and `v = "1024"`... Hope you got me.

Comment: @user180574 I came up with [a solution that doesn't use an extra variable in the parallel assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22522211/456814).

Answer (score 4):

```
config.each do |items|
  items.each do |key, value|
    # e.g. key="file", value="/var/tmp", etc.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@Arup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22516713/456814), here's a solution that doesn't require a extra, unused variable in the parallel assignment:

```
config.each do |hash|
  key, value = hash.to_a[0]
end
```

`to_a` converts the hash into the same kind of array that you would get by using splat `*hash`, but you can actually index the first element of the array (i.e. the first key/value pair) with `[0]` this way, while trying to do so with splat `(*hash)` generates a syntax error (at least in Ruby version 2.1.1):

```
>> k,v = (*hash)[0]
SyntaxError: (irb):4: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '='
k,v = (*x)[0]
          ^
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>>
```

Of course, depending on what you're going to do with the `key` and `value` variables, it might make your code shorter and more readable to use one of these standard block constructs:

```
config.each do |hash|
  hash.each { |key,value| puts "#{key}: #{value}" }
end

# or

config.each do |hash|
  hash.each do |key,value|
    puts "#{key}: #{value}"
  end
end
```